# È usuale questo uso del vocabolo "taglierino"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Nelle notizie di Euronews ho letto questa frase (il corsivo è mio):

> In Francia vengono celebrati come eroi i passeggeri, fra i quali due soldati statunitensi, che hanno disarmato l’uomo salito con un kalashnikov, nove caricatori, una pistola e un *taglierino*.

Ho cercato la parola "taglierino" nei principali dizionari d'italiano online e in quasi tutti appare un tipo di pasta come unica definizione. Soltanto nel [Sabatini Coletti](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/T/taglierino.shtml) ho trovato l'accezione di "taglierino" come "temperino". Alla voce ["temperino"](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/T/temperino.shtml) si trova

> Piccolo coltello tascabile con una o più lame ripiegabili nel manico.

Il fatto che questa definizione non si trovi in altri dizionari ha attirato la mia attenzione. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: è usuale l'uso di "taglierino" con questo significato?

Comment: ["cor tajerino convinco anche 'a tizia"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=meboY6umDSE) -> chiara l'accezione di strumento/arma qui : P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anche lo Zingarelli (che non è consultabile liberamente) riporta, come seconda accezione: «piccolo attrezzo fornito di una sottile lama retrattile, usato per tagliare carta e sim. SIN. cutter».

E, per il poco che vale, a me è più familiare questo significato che quello delle tagliatelle sottili.

Comment: Sottoscrivo in pieno che la prima cosa che mi viene in mente pensando a "taglierino" sia quello per la carta e non la pasta.

Answer (score 5):

***[Taglierino](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=taglierino):*** (Garzanti)

> - attrezzo manuale con lama retrattile per tagliare materiale in fogli

[image]

C'è anche al femminile ***[taglierina](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/T/taglierina.shtml)***:

> - Piccolo attrezzo formato da una lama a scorrimento fissata a un manico da una vite.
>     (a. 1931)

L'uso al maschile sembra essere più recente come risulta da

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=taglierina%2Ctaglierino&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctaglierina%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctaglierino%3B%2Cc0) taglierina vs taglierino.

Comment: Per taglierina sapevo che solitamente si intendesse [questa](http://www.millerotoli.com/files/taglierina%20a%20leva%20con%20paramano%20rotante%20565.bmp). La sua esistenza potrebbe ulteriormente falsare l'Ngram, come pure l'esistenza di taglierino come sinonimo di coltellino.

Comment: @Zachiel - infatti ho detto "***sembra"*** essere più recente. Penso valga la pena mostrarlo in quanto taglierina sembra essere in uso dagli anni 30, mentre il termine "taglierino", in ogni sua  forma, si è diffuso successivamente.

Comment: Mio padre usava per lavoro, credo già dagli anni '50, quello che lui chiamava _taglierina_ e oggi, a quanto pare, si chiama più spesso _taglierino_. Mio padre è uno al quale è sempre piaciuto usare i termini corretti, o perlomeno, in mancanza di altre informazioni, i termini più usati a Roma. Essendo abituato a dire taglierina anch'io, sono rimasto sorpreso dal trovare su Amazon principalmente taglierine nel senso "linkato" da @Zachiel. Cercando "taglierina Stanley" (la Stanley non fa taglierine nel senso di @Zachiel) ottengo 10 risultati, mentre cercando "taglierino Stanley" ne ottengo 40.